# Facebook Still returns timestamp format

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Starting with the 'Events Timezone' migration, Facebook changed the timesptamp time formatting to UTC. 
I am developing a native android app and running fql query for fetching user's info.
Problem is I am still getting time as timestamp instead of UTC, though when trying to run a simple fql via GRAPH-API tool I am getting time in UTC format.

Events Timezone Migration Note on facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/

Does anyone experiencing the same thing?

Comment: Have you __enabled__ the migration in your app’s settings in the app dashboard …?

Comment: On the “advanced” settings tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on facebook app settings:
apps->edit app->advance-> and enable Events Timezone

(as CBroe suggested)